# the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened

Tags: vsto

I want to install outlook add-ins (Which is developed by Visual studio 2008) but I've got following error.

Name: 
From: file:///D:/Project/.Net Learning/OutlookAddIn3/OutlookAddIn3/bin/Debug/app.publish/OutlookAddIn3.vsto

Exception reading manifest from file:///D:/Project/.Net%20Learning/OutlookAddIn3/OutlookAddIn3/bin/Debug/app.publish/OutlookAddIn3.vsto: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.

************** Exception Text **************
System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Exception reading manifest from file:///D:/Project/.Net%20Learning/OutlookAddIn3/OutlookAddIn3/bin/Debug/app.publish/OutlookAddIn3.vsto: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. ---> System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Deployment manifest is not semantically valid. ---> System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Deployment manifest requires that you specify a publisher and a product.
   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSemanticsForDeploymentRole()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSemanticsForDeploymentRole()
   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSemantics(ManifestType manifestType)
   at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.GetManifests(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your windows registered name have a special character like "*". I suggested to you change windows registered name. you can change it from registry in (Win XP):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion

change value of these keys:
RegisteredOrganization
RegisteredOwner

Comment: I have a similar issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61980065/1232087). I checked my windows registered name at the place you suggested, it does not have a special character. It simply reads `Toshiba` - and that is the name of my laptop. Any other suggestions/comments?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super old, thought I'd share.  This is what fixed it for me:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4e4ee82b-308e-41ea-a8ad-0ea465aec3f5/the-manifest-may-not-be-valid-or-the-file-could-not-be-opened?forum=winformssetup

The short of it is my Installation folder URL was wrong.