# There is not enough free memory to run this program, Outlook MAPI Error - MailItem.SaveAs method C#

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, mapi

Hello I am using the following code to download the email which has around 20+ attachments(~ 9MB) through Outlook Addin, and getting the following error - There is not enough free memory to run this program. Quit one or more programs and then try again. The exception throws as MailItem.SaveAs method to save MSG to local temp path. I have tried with the kb fix available to change the registry settings which doesn't help here.

```
        if (mailItem.Subject != null)
    {
        fileName = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Aggregate(mailItem.Subject, (current, c) => current.Replace(c.ToString(), string.Empty));
    }


    fileName = mailindex + "- " + fileName + ".msg";
    var fullPath = CustomUtility.TrimFilePath(location, fileName);
    emailItemDetails.MsgFileName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);

    mailItem.SaveAs(fullPath, OlSaveAsType.olMSG);

    int attachmentIndex = 1;
    foreach (Attachment attachment in mailItem.Attachments)
    {
        string attachmentName = mailindex + "-" + string.Format("{0:00}", attachmentIndex) + " " + attachment.FileName;
        var attachmentPath = CustomUtility.TrimFilePath(location, attachmentName);
        attachment.SaveAsFile(attachmentPath);
        attachmentIndex++;
    }
```

Below is the exception I could see in eventvwr.

> Customization URI: file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Common
>   Files/Microsoft Shared/VSTA/Pipeline.v10.0/PipelineSegments.store
>   Exception: Exception reading manifest from
>   file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Common%20Files/Microsoft%20Shared/VSTA/Pipeline.v10.0/PipelineSegments.store:
>   the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
>
> ************** Exception Text ************** System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Exception
>   reading manifest from
>   file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Common%20Files/Microsoft%20Shared/VSTA/Pipeline.v10.0/PipelineSegments.store:
>   the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. --->
>   System.Xml.XmlException: '', hexadecimal value 0x01, is an invalid
>   character. Line 1, position 1.

Please help if you have any suggestions

Comment: You can try to delete the following registry entry:(Please back up your registry entries before deleting)
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\outlook\Addins\[YourAdd-in]\Warmup For more information, please see the following link:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/83382a34-5087-40cf-b12a-1121303627c0/systemdeploymentapplicationinvaliddeploymentexception?forum=vsto and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054364/the-manifest-may-not-be-valid-or-the-file-could-not-be-opened

Comment: Its not an deployment issue, In fact it was able to download for other emails except the ones which are having 20+ email attachments. Even the mail with >10MB documents works well

Comment: if so,There may be a problem with your fullpath format. You can output the fullpath to see if it is correct. please see the following link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: thanks for reply. we don't see issues with fullpath which is being used for saving into local drive path and able to download for email which has 17 email attachments. if it goes beyond, it errors out.